# Stick Figure Animation Using Line Animation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, animation, matrix, euler-angles, line-plot

I am trying to animate a motion file using the Matlab *drawnow* function and line plotting. The motion file has both 3x3 euler angles (yaw-pitch-roll) and XYZ coordinate values and I plan on using line plotting to create a stick figure animation where each body segment is animated as a stick figure.

Currently my code is:

```
%% Import data from text file.
%% Perform Calculations on data

%% Draw initial figure
figure(1)
hold on

set(gcf,'Renderer','OpenGL')
lua = plot(luaX(1),luaY(1),luaZ(1),0,'o','MarkerSize',10,'MarkerFaceColor','b');
set(lua,'EraseMode','normal');

rua = plot(ruaX(1),ruaY(1),ruaZ(1),0,'o','MarkerSize',10,'MarkerFaceColor','r');
set(rua,'EraseMode','normal');

%% Animate the rest
i = 1; 

while i <= length(time)

    % Delete previous line
    if i > 1
        delete(l_lua);
        delete(l_rua);
    end

    % Set data and draw line
    set(lua,'XData',luaX(i));
    set(lua,'YData',luaY(i));
    set(lua,'ZData',luaZ(i));
    l_lua = line([-200 luaX(i)],[0 luaY(i)],[0 luaZ(i)],'LineWidth',2,'EraseMode','normal');
    set(rua,'XData',ruaX(i));
    set(rua,'YData',ruaY(i));
    set(rua,'ZData',ruaZ(i));
    l_rua = line([200 ruaX(i)],[0 ruaY(i)],[0 ruaZ(i)],'LineWidth',2,'EraseMode','normal');
    drawnow;

    % Draw Figure
    grid on
    axis([-1000 1000 -1000 1000 -1000 1000]);
    xlabel('X Axis');
    ylabel('Y Axis');
    zlabel('Z Axis');

    i = i + 1;

end
```

The code above only includes the X,Y, and Z values of the line but not it's orientation using the Euler angles.

How can I add the 3x3 euler angles to the line being drawn? I would like to add both coordinate and Euler angle values to the line plot. Do I convert Euler angles to rotation matrix and create a 4x4 matrix (with XYZ values) and plot with that? Any input would be helpful.

My goal is to create a stick figure that is represented by lines animated in using the above approach but I don't mind experimenting with other methods. Are there other more efficient ways to create and animate a stick figure?

Thanks for all who contribute.

Comment: If you have X,Y,Z of both ends of a line you don't need any angles to plot it. How do your X,Y,Z and angle values define the line you're trying to draw? (Sketching it out for the 2D case might help).

Comment: I already know how to plot the line without the angles, but the Euler angles are used for orientation of the line (i.e. rotation about a relative coordinate). I just want to know how to include them in the line plot. For example, do I replace the luaX, luaY, and luaZ with a 4x4 matrix instead of the current scaler form, if so can you show me how?

Comment: Your example is still unclear to me - do you have coordinates for where your lines start off and then rotations you want to apply to them?  If so, just apply the rotation to your coordinates (e.g. define and apply a rotation matrix), then plot the line using those new coordinates.